# Reference Request: Bregman's Inequality

Tags: reference-request

Bregman's Inequality gives an upper bound on the permanent of a given 0-1 matrix given only the row sums. Although there are now a number of different proofs I have not been able to find Bregman's original proof. In particular I have not been able to find the paper "Some properties of nonnegative matrices and their permanents", Soviet Math. Dokl., 15: 945–949" or any other writeup of this original proof and was curious as to where I could find it?

Comment: http://www.worldcat.org/title/soviet-mathematics-doklady/oclc/5417745

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I went to the library and couldn't find it, but it turns out the citation in the OP and in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bregman%E2%80%93Minc_inequality) is mistaken, the volume number is 14 rather than 15 (page numbers 945–949 are correct); in any case, I located the article and scanned it; I'm not sure posting the scan here is "[fair use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use)", but I will gladly email it if you drop me a line.

I have corrected the citation in the Wikipedia article.

Comment: Where can I email you?